# Orthogonal projection of vector on $W$ and $W^{\perp}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W = ax+by+cz+d =0$ a plane.

And suppose give a vector $v = (l,m,n)$

I want to find the orthogonal projection on $W$ and $W^{\perp}$.

First of all, from the normal vector $n=(a,b,c)$, I can estimate the projection on the plane as follow

\begin{align}
\textrm{proj}_{W}(v) = v - \textrm{proj}_{n} v = v - \frac{v \cdot n}{n \cdot n} n 
\end{align}
How about $W^{\perp}$?

In a sense, I noticed that $\textrm{proj}_{W^{\perp}} = I - \textrm{proj}_{W}$, then

\begin{align}
\textrm{proj}_{W^{\perp}}(v) = v - \textrm{proj}_{W} v =  \frac{v \cdot n}{n \cdot n} n 
\end{align}
am I right?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Your projection formula is only valid when $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$, i.e., when $d=0$. Your question doesn’t have this restriction. Furthermore, what do you mean by $W^\perp$ when $W$ isn’t a subspace?

Comment: @amd, thanks for the clarification.